# Capturing and saving picture to specific path

Tags: c#, path, save, directory

Trying to make a program that will take screenshots of my monitors screens and will save them to a path that I'll specific using a button see Button1_Click. I then save it to the properties settings, and loading it every time the program starts, however even though at TakeScreenshotBtn_Click where bmpScreen.Save is, I can't seem to save it to the specific path. Either it will save it to where the .exe is running
or it will simply do nothing. I used @label2.text. It throws a GDI+ Error.

Capture screen:

```cs
var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                              Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                              PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                0,
                                0,
                                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                LogTxtBox.AppendText("[#] Captured whole monitor." + Environment.NewLine);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                label2.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.SavingPath.ToString();
                bmpScreenshot.Save(label2.Text + "Capture-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-h-mm-tt") + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);

                LogTxtBox.AppendText("[#] Saved screenshot under name : " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-h-mm-tt") + Environment.NewLine);
```

Set path:

```cs
DialogResult result = SetFolderPath.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SetFolderPath.SelectedPath)) {
    string Path = SetFolderPath.SelectedPath;
    ClickNShare.Properties.Settings.Default.SavingPath = Path;
    ClickNShare.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    MessageBox.Show("Path set to: " + Path.ToString(), "Path set!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    LogTxtBox.AppendText("[#] Path set to: " + Path.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Annnnd what does the debugger say on this line? `bmpScreenshot.Save`

Comment: That's the thing, debugger says nothing apparently there's no error

Comment: [Navigate through code with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Instead of generating the filename inside `bmpScreenshot.Save()`, extract that out to a variable, then log that variable's value to the console (or just inspect it with the debugger) and validate that it's what you expect.

Comment: Also, you should wrap that `gfxScreenshot` in a `using`, just as matter of good code hygiene.

Comment: @Blorgbeard that fixed my issue, and helped me to determine I was low minded.
I was forgetting to do 

a `/` after the actual path I was setting

     


is the way I got it working

Comment: Use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine).